# Can't acces Json data and plot line on canvas d3js

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, d3.js

I would like to load data from a Json file and then print the line inside a canvas tag with d3js v4.
The same code worked with a TSV file (obviously changing requestJson in requestTsv), but i can't manage to get it working with a JSON.

Edit:
Thanks to Gerardo I understood that the files are different as the TSV is formed by objects {x: value, y: value} and the Json is an object with two arrays, how can I access the data inside the x and y arrays of the Json file?

I'm sure something is wrong here:

```
d3.requestJson("dato.json", function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
  context.beginPath();
  line(data);
  context.lineWidth = 1.5;
  context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
  context.stroke();
});
```

This is the Json file:

```
{
"chart": {
    "y": [57, 92, 30, 91, 56, 20],
    "x": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}}
```

Here the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<canvas width="960" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = canvas.width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = canvas.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .context(context);

context.translate(margin.left, margin.top);

d3.requestJson("dato.json", function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));



  context.beginPath();
  line(data);
  context.lineWidth = 1.5;
  context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
  context.stroke();
});




</script>
```

This is the TSV file:

```js
x y
1 93.24
2 95.35
3 98.84
4 99.92
5 99.80
6 99.47
7 100.39
8 100.40
9 100.81
```

Comment: the json data has no `x` property in the root, so `d.x = +d.x` will fail

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda, so i have to put data there? and how can i access an object with two arrays in d3?

Comment: @Omar, I deleted my answer because, despite being sure that d3.json don't accept accessors, I'm not sure about d3.requestJson, but I'll search. Meanwhile, I undeleted the answer.

Comment: @Gerardo Ah ok, as i'm very new to stack overflow i thought i deleted it! Anyway really thank you for your help

Comment: Another thing: don't edit your question to ask *another* question. It's very confusing for the readers! The problem in this one (accessing data) was solved. So, close it and ask *another* question regarding how to structure your data.

Comment: Correct, thank you! :)

Comment: A word of caution: you are still using an **alpha** version of D3 v4! Many things have changed in the final version, though. The method `d3.requestJson()` you are using is no longer available in this final release. It was removed by commit [14717ea](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/commit/14717ea3c040829d19d181f257d9681c41367059) *"Shorter names for convenience methods!"* Using an alpha version may itself be the root of many issues. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @altocumulus you are right, that's because i modified a block from Mike bostock that was developed when the stable version was not released! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems, and my answer will cover just the first one.

First, all this part between `"data.json"` and `function(error, data)` is what we can an "accessor":

```
function(d) {
   d.x = +d.x;
   d.y = +d.y;
   return d;
},
```

Basically, it changes strings to numbers. But here is the problem: `d3.csv` and  `d3.tsv` can have accessors, but `d3.json` *cannot* have an accessor (neither `d3.requestJson`). You'll have to remove all this and converting strings to numbers inside the callback.

But you have a second problem, that I can't help (unless you post your TSV): changing `d3.tsv` to `d3.json` is not enough. If you don't want to change the code, you have to create a JSON that matches the structure that `d3.tsv` creates with your TSV, which is an array of objects (using your tsv version, console.log the data: that's the structure you'll have to match). Right now, your code won't work with that JSON you have.

Edit:

Based on the TSV file you shared on your question, you have to create an JSON exactly like this:

```
[
    {"x": 1, "y": 93.24},
    {"x": 2, "y": 95.35},
    {"x": 3, "y": 98.84},
    ...
]
```

That is, an array of objects.

Comment: So I have to use number() js function to get numbers from json and do something like:

d3.requestJson("../file.json", function(data) {
  // i have to use the data here inside this function
});
//data here won't work

If i understood correctly my question now is how can i access the Json structure? Because i think that the Json structure is better than the TSV one.

Comment: @Omar, I edited the answer to show you how to create your JSON.